# Set an xml background for linear layout and show its press effect

Tags: android, xml

I want to set following xml shape as my linear layout background:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:shape="rectangle">
    <stroke
        android:width="2dp"
        android:color="#D50000">
    </stroke>
    <solid
        android:color="@android:color/transparent">
    </solid>
</shape>
```

And I also want to show the press effect by these lines of code:

```
android:clickable="true"
android:focusable="true"
android:foreground="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
android:background="?android:selectableItemBackground"
```

But as you know, it is impossible to have two `background` for a view. So, What is the solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_margin="16dp"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    android:background="@drawable/ll_background"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:onClick="doSomething"
    android:padding="8dp"
    android:weightSum="3">

    <TextView
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Greeting" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_weight="2"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Hello World!" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Then in drawable/ folder add:

button_normal.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:shape="rectangle">
    <stroke
        android:width="2dp"
        android:color="#D50000">
    </stroke>

</shape>
```

button_pressed.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:shape="rectangle">
    <solid
        android:color="#D50000">
    </solid>
    <stroke android:color="#D50000" android:width="2dp"/>
</shape>
```

Then create ll_background.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@drawable/button_pressed"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/button_normal"/>
</selector>
```

Finally for ripple create drawable-v21 folder and add ll_background.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ripple xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:color="#D50000">
    <item>
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="@android:color/white" />
            <stroke
                android:color="#D50000"
                android:width="1dp" />
        </shape>
    </item>
</ripple>
```

The first three files (button_normal.xml, button_pressed.xml & ll_background.xml) will be for api < 21 and the 4th (ll_background.xml) ripple will be on all other devices including api 21 and above.